# NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation after removing kotlin-android-extensions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kapt

I am in the process of removing the deprecated kotlin-android-extensions. It worked fine for one project but with another one I am stuck now.
As soon as I remove the extension I am getting:

```
 incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation @error.NonExistentClass()
```

for classes that use Room.

```
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

but this did not help. I do not yet see the correlation.

Comment: Room itself does not need `kotlin-android-extensions` -- I removed that plugin from a bunch of Room sample projects without issue. I assume that you have already done the typical sort of steps like clean-and-rebuild the project. Do all your Room-related classes result in that error, or only some? If the latter, is there anything notable in common between them?

Answer (score 11):

Ah - I found the reason. `kotlin-android-extensions` also provides @Parcelize
And I used @Parcelize for classes that room processes.
Adding the plugin `kotlin-parcelize` solves the problem